# Documentation of NDSolve`FEM`FEMNintegrate

Tags: finite-element-method

Where can I find detailed information concerning the `` NDSolve`FEM` `` package?

Thanks!

Comment: FEMDocumentation/tutorial/FiniteElementOverview and also FEMDocumentation/tutorial/FiniteElementProgramming  and FEMDocumentation/guide/FiniteElementMethodGuide?

Comment: @Syed Thanks for your reply. Especialy I'm looking for `NDSolve\`FEM\`FEMNintegrate` 
and could not find any information

Comment: The code may be inspected with ``GeneralUtilities`PrintDefinitions@NDSolve`FEM`FEMNIntegrate``

Comment: @MichaelE2 This helps, thank you very much.

Answer (score 2):

FEMNIntegrate is not documented because it should be used through `NIntegrate`. `NIntegrate` will decide when to call FEMNIntegrate.

Comment: Can you please clarify how one can encourage `NIntegrate` to do such a call?